# How to collect history of deleted posts?

Tags: support, data-explorer, deleted-questions, revisions-list, migrated-questions

When a question migrates, answers are deleted and the question left as a stub. For example, a question is migrated from site superuser (post id: 82342) to stack overflow (post id: 1894170). I can access the edit history of 82342 (https://superuser.com/posts/82342/revisions), but my question: is it possible to collect that information from any data dump? The stack exchange data dump (PostHistory) does not contain any information about the deleted post (I have seen PostsWithDeleted in SEDE but that does not contain history).

Answer (score 2):

Content of posts which are outright deleted can't be accessed through SEDE; you'll need other tricks to download them altogether, like an [Apple Script](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/tools/tree/master/revision-downloader).

It [looks like](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/941257) that upon migration a question, only the final version of a post is migrated, so there is no way to get the complete history from SEDE.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I guess that's a design choice to remove the old history. That means if the migration rejection event occurs in the new site (this can happen if the migrated question is closed on the new site and eventually removed), the question will return back to the original site but it will appear as a new post. Is this correct?

Comment: Eh ... not exactly. [This rejected migrated question](https://superuser.com/questions/1379116/adastra-systems-500-030-single-board-pc-keyboard-connection-help) is still closed on [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/409330/adastra-systems-500-030-single-board-pc-keyboard-connection-help) (but no longer 'migrated').

Comment: you said there is no way to get the complete history from SEDE. I am wondering whether that data is stored separately but not publicly available or the history is lost completely?

Comment: It's still stored, 10K users (and the post owners) can see it.

Comment: Is it possible to get access to that data as a data dump or another way(such as for research purpose) ? what is the proper way to get access to that data?

Comment: There is no proper way, but I've constructed an Apple Script to download all revisions of certain posts, including deleted ones (if you have enough reputation). It's linked to in the answer already.